# Is it possible to make React-Electron Standalone app stay always on top?

Tags: reactjs, windows, electron

I haven't implemented anything yet. I want to make sure first if it's possible. Sorry, there isn't any code. I want to create a standalone app for Windows, which remains on top, no matter what application is open. Is it possible? If not with React-Electron, then any alternatives? Please provide me alternatives even if it works with React-Electron, please! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible according to electron docs. options for window

> alwaysOnTop Boolean (optional) - Whether the window should always stay on top of other windows. Default is false.

more info [Electron Window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow)